# Example of EJB 3x project on Intellij Idea?

Tags: jboss, intellij-idea, ejb-3.0

I am a Java user with recent migration to IntelliJ Idea and I am new to EJB, I wonder if there is any example of EJB 3.x example with IntelliJ Idea and JBoss 6? I did not found much material myself.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of EJB examples here:

- http://openejb.apache.org/examples-trunk/

All of them have unit tests and can be run in Intellij (my preferred IDE by far) by either:

- importing the Maven pom.xml as a new module or project
- using Maven `mvn idea:idea` to generate the Intellij project

Here's one example with an accompanying video that shows it run in Intellij.

- http://openejb.apache.org/examples-trunk/simple-stateless
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aLx2jta96xU

No audio in the video, point is to show it working.  Seeing is believing as they say :)

It's not JBoss, but will teach you EJB and the knowledge is transferable.